# Error installing pymssql on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: python, pymssql

I have XCode installed and also FreeTDS. I tried to connect to my SQL Server and it works perfect.

Now I have to develop an aplication on python that works with this SQL Server and I´m trying to install pymsql, but I got this error when I launche sudo python setup.py command:

```
==> sudo python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pymssql.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pymssql.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pymssql.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pymssql.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'pymssql.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
skipping '_mssql.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building '_mssql' extension
llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/sw/include -Ifreetds/nix_64/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetds -I/opt/local/freetds/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
_mssql.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6_mssql_15MSSQLConnection_convert_python_value’:
_mssql.c:7322: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
_mssql.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6_mssql_15MSSQLConnection_get_result’:
_mssql.c:9554: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
_mssql.c:9566: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
_mssql.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6_mssql_20MSSQLStoredProcedure_2bind’:
_mssql.c:11146: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
llvm-gcc-4.2 -Wl,-F. -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/_mssql.o -L/sw/lib -Lfreetds/nix_64/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib/freetds -L/opt/local/freetds/lib -lsybdb -lrt -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/_mssql.so
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/sw/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib/freetds'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/freetds/lib'
ld: library not found for -lrt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/sw/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib/freetds'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/freetds/lib'
ld: library not found for -lrt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc6eQsIN.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Any help or clue?

Comment: have you created the folders : "/sw/lib" , "/opt/local/lib" ... ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, pymssql's setup.py (as of version pymssql-2.0.0b1-dev-20111019) needs a bit of help to work properly on OSX Lion.  The current setup.py tries to compile/link against some pre-built Linux FreeTDS libraries, and also tries to link against librt, which doesn't exist on OSX.  Additionally, it only explicitly looks for FreeTDS libraries from Fink or MacPorts, so if you've installed Homebrew (if you use if) or FreeTDS itself in a non-standard location, it may not be located by compiler/linker.

I created a repaired version of setup.py [**here**](http://code.google.com/r/dinkypumpkin-pymssql/source/browse/setup.py). It worked well enough for me with the Homebrew build of FreeTDS using the standard locations (/usr/local/{lib, include}), but as always YMMV. You may need to adjust setup.py further if you've installed FreeTDS in a different location. You can generally ignore the warnings from the linker about missing directories that may not exist on your system:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/freetds'

One other note: You will probably have built FreeTDS for a single architecture, likely x86_64.  By default, pymssl will be a multi-architecture build (assuming you're using the system Python 2.7.1), so even with a patched setup.py you will see a linker warning something like:

ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libsybdb.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

That warning just indicates that the FreeTDS libraries only have  single architecture version to link against.  You can avoid the warning by using ARCHFLAGS to make a x86_64-only build:

ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" python setup.py install

Comment: +1 Good explanation and linking to the setup.py helped get things working right.

Answer (score 4):

Or, try this fork, it installs without issues:

https://github.com/blackbass1988/pymssql-macos-lion

To install on OS X Mavericks, you need

OS X Command Line Tools

FreeTDS

```
brew install freetds
```

Cython

```
pip install cython
```

and then finally you can install the pymssql-macoslion

```
pip install git+git://github.com/blackbass1988/pymssql-macos-lion.git@master
```

Answer (score 2):

Just incase anyone is reading this the following worked for me:

```
brew install freetds
sudo pip install pymssql
```