# Error when installing numpy package in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

My Python is 3.4, and I try to use both

```
 pip install numpy
 pip3 install numpy
```

to install the package. And I also use the "Project Interpreter" to install the numpy. The interpreter is the 3.4.1, but there always be an error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What should I do to install it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you add screenshots of what you did?

Comment: looks like mac os related

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Using Python 3.4.4  i did the following though PyCharm and did not encounter any Errors:

File:Setting - Project interpreter
[image]

Browsed for numpy and installed:

[image]

For MAC OS related issue:

[Error installing pymssql on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161770/error-installing-pymssql-on-mac-os-x-lion)

> brew install numpy and/or sudo pip install numpy

[Can't install Orange: "error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238458/cant-install-orange-error-command-clang-failed-with-exit-status-1)

> Problem solved: Xcode 4 doesn't actually come with gcc-4.2; it comes
>   with the new LLVM compilers.
>
> > It was just a matter of doing:
> >
> > export CC=llvm-gcc-4.2
> >
> > export CXX=llvm-g++-4.2

[gcc-4.2 failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473066/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-status-1)
Try the following:

> Install the latest Xcode. From Xcode's Preferences menu, install the
>   Command Line Tools (Downloads/Components tab).

Comment: Thanks! The same I did, but I got the second error~~

Comment: did you click on the link and validate that this is your case?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running OSX try installing it with brew:

```
brew install numpy
```

[This guy](https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/02/25/scientific-python-on-mac-os-x-10-9-with-homebrew/) did it and I think I have a vague recollection that I did it in the past on OSX without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The creator of numpy co-founded a company that puts out a Python distribution etc.. which includes (no surprise) Numpy.   You can [download Anaconda for Python 3.x here](http://continuum.io/downloads)

It won't mess up your systems python.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while installing NUMPY package in PYCHARM. It said that it requires microsoft visual C++ 14.00 .But, all I did was reinstalled the PYCHARM in C drive and then tried to install the package.It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, you can install `Scipy` and `Numpy` both using `brew`